# With air resistance, why does the horizontal range decrease and why is it steeper during the descent phase?

Tags: kinematics, symmetry, projectile

IN RELATION TO PROJECTILE MOTION

I've been trying to grasp this concept but cannot figure it out.
[image]

From what i understand, the x-component only has air resistance acting on it so it slows it down quite a bit in the horizontal direction. I'm not sure how to correlate this concept with explaining the distorted shape of the curve though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s because air resistance is acting in both directions. Air surrounds the entire projectile and not just the surface facing the x-direction.

If you look at the diagram above you will note that the vector $\vec F_{ar}$ has components in both the $x$ and $y$ directions.

It gets steeper in the later phase of its flight since it is experiencing this resistance force - which is proportional to $v^2$ - for the greatest amount of time (prior to just falling almost straight to the ground).

Comment: Thank you, I think i get it now !!

Comment: That’s  ok. Good luck!

Comment: @sophia if youhave got your answer then please click on the tick on left side of the appropriate answer